# existence of uncountable well-ordered set admitting a special type of function

Tags: set-theory, well-orders

Does there exist an uncountable Well-ordered set $(X,<)$ and a function $f: X \times X \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x,y)<f(x,z),\forall x<y<z$ ?

Note that if we want $X$ to be countable, then such a set up exists, for instance take $f: \mathbb N\times\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ to be $f(a,b)=|a-b|,\forall a,b \in \mathbb N$.

Unfortunately, I am unable to find such an uncountable $X$.

Please help

Comment: If $x$ is the smallest element of $X$, there are uncountably many members of $X$ larger than $x$, and your condition would imply the existence of a strictly increasing uncountable sequence of reals. But no such sequence exists.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: what do you mean by "strictly increasing uncountable sequence of real numbers" ... ?

Comment: A map $g\!:X\smallsetminus\{x\}\to\mathbb R$ that is strictly increasing. In a sense, it doesn't exist because $\mathbb Q$ is countable.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: there should be more to it than just $\mathbb Q$ being countable ... for example strictly increasing maps from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ exists ... are you saying that if $(Z,<)$ is well-ordered and uncountable, then strictly increasing function from $Z$ to $\mathbb R$ doesn't exist ?

Comment: Yes. In set theory, a "sequence" is a function with domain a well-ordered set.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: I see ... thanks ... can you please give a proof as to why such a strictly increasing function cannot exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $(X,<)$ is an uncountable well-ordered set.

**Claim:**

There does not exist a function $f: X{\,\times\,}X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x,y,z\in X$, if $x < y < z$ then $f(x,y) < f(x,z)$.

**Proof:**

Suppose such a function $f$ exists.

For $x\in X$, let $x^{*}$ denote the successor of $x$.

Let $x_0$ denote the least element of $X$, and let $S=X{\,\setminus}\{x_0\}$.

Then $f(x_0,s) < f(x_0,s^{*})$, for all $s\in S$.

For each $s\in S$, let $g(s)$ be a rational number such that $f(x_0,s) < g(s) < f(x_0,s^{*})$.

Then $g$ is a function from $S$ to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Since $X$ is uncountable, so is $S$, and since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, so is $g(S)$.

Hence $g$ is not injective.

Let $a,b\in S$ with $a < b$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&x_0 < a < b\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x_0 < a < a^{*}\le b < b^{*}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&f(x_0,a) < f(x_0,a^{*})\le f(x_0,b) < f(x_0,b^{*})\\[4pt]
\implies\;&g(a) < g(b)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so $g$ is strictly increasing, hence injective, contradiction.